# CNAME settings in s3 with cloudflare doesn't work

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm currenly trying to use amazon s3 as image hosting through cloudflare.
I would like to use my subdomain as image url.

I set CNAME in cloudflare like below.

```
image.domain.com  CNAME  image.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

my bucket name in s3 is　image.domain.com

But I got error below when I go to image.domain.com

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
  <ArgumentValue>Basic dGFiaXBlZGlhc3RhZmdedaefaeeYW5jZQ==</ArgumentValue
  <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
  <RequestId>4EEDAB31EAD3C24F1</RequestId>
<HostId>
  DbqMpmzTxU4c/gE4uC6fadaebwtb35wtggtbrtbtt vIm5IZC9lg1xDoixF
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have to use website hosting in s3 for this setting? or I missed some configurations..?

Comment: You ever figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like more of an issue with S3, from what I can see. Some general tips about [S3 and CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-).

Comment: thanks for information,
but I've read this before the settings :(